# Stanford Parser (Typed Dependencee) Exception

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, nlp, stanford-nlp

I want to see Dependence output format in Stanford Parser for NLP. I downloaded the jar file from this link.
http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml

Then I import it in Eclipse and wrote following code.

```
package hammad.NLP;

import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import com.chaoticity.dependensee.Main;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser;
import edu.stanford.nlp.process.CoreLabelTokenFactory;
import edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer;
import edu.stanford.nlp.process.TokenizerFactory;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.GrammaticalStructure;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.GrammaticalStructureFactory;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.PennTreebankLanguagePack;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreebankLanguagePack;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TypedDependency;

public class Test {
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try
    {

        String text = "A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
        TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
        GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();
        LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel("C:/Stanford Parser/Java/stanford-parser-full-2015-04-20/stanford-parser-3.5.2-models/edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz");
        lp.setOptionFlags(new String[]{"-maxLength", "500", "-retainTmpSubcategories"});
        TokenizerFactory<CoreLabel> tokenizerFactory =
                PTBTokenizer.factory(new CoreLabelTokenFactory(), "");
        List<CoreLabel> wordList = tokenizerFactory.getTokenizer(new StringReader(text)).tokenize();
        Tree tree = lp.apply(wordList);    
        GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(tree);
        Collection<TypedDependency> tdl = gs.typedDependenciesCCprocessed(true);

        Main.writeImage(tree,tdl, "image.png",3);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

It gives following Exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TypedDependency.gov()Ledu/stanford/nlp/trees/TreeGraphNode;
```

I searched for TypedDependency and found that gov() exist in it but exception is coming. I searched a lot about it but found no help regarding this. I will be thankful to you if you help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to incompatibility between recent releases of Stanford NLP code and DependenSee, which was built against v2.0.5 (2013-04-05) of the Stanford Parser. If you comment out the line `Main.writeImage(tree,tdl, "image.png",3);` and instead just do `System.out.println(tdl);` then it works fine.

Your options are either to: not use DependenSee, fix DependenSee to be compatible with recent Stanford NLP releases (probably easy), or to downgrade to an old version of the Stanford NLP....